# Is there any problem using brass screws to fit zinc hinges?

Tags: screws, hinges

I have a set of brass screws that fit the zinc hinges and in the interests of not wasting money and resources, I thought I could just use them together.

I realise that they may look a bit odd, but they won't be on show and may yet be painted.  I was just concerned that they may be weak or not work well together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it gets wet at all, you will run into problems with galvanic corrosion that will eat away at the hinges.  Your best bet is to use materials of similar anodic index (near the bottom of [this page on galvanic corrosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_corrosion)).  If you absolutely must pair brass and zinc, either ensure that the connection between the two will never get wet (using grease or some sort of coating) or that the two metals never actually come into contact with one another (using, say, a nonmetallic washer).

Comment: I think that you understate the corrosion issue, but yes.

Comment: Brass is a copper/zinc alloy, so I would have expected minimal galvanic action as long as the zinc on the hinge was intact.  But according to the link, that clearly isn't the case.  +1

Answer (score 1):

You surely have galvanized steel hinges, which are zinc coated steel, not plain zinc. This is to avoid quick rust. In the long term, they will rust, as will any galvanized, which will eventually fail, but you should not have a problem  for quite some time, so I would not worry as it would be an easy fix anyway. The right thing to do, would be to use stainless steel.
To clarify, **brass contains zinc in it**, so there is no problem mixing both metals.